# Getting error "No string associated with token" when MSI is deployed

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll

I created a web application MSI and deployed to server and when trying to run application, I am getting this error:

> [C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\srmweb\cb19c141\c9255aa5\assembly\dl3\9343819a\00cb4764_979ece01\SoapExtensionLibrary.DLL]
>   No string associated with token.

The specified DLL is copied to bin folder as a part of MSI installation. When I copy the dll to a different location and copy the same dll back to the bin folder. The applciation works fine.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If copying the DLL sorts it out, can you confirm if a `iisreset` does the same? and then if recycling the IIS App Pool does the same? try narrow it down some more.

Comment: I did recycle app pool and resetted IIS. Didn't make a difference.